# 2D Geometry: How to determine the closest surrounding lines given an internal point?

Tags: c#, geometry, 2d, autocad

I am looking to replicate the functionality provided by the AutoCAD BOUNDARY command. Given a 2D point in a drawing, I need to find all the closest line segments that surround that point.

This image depicts a drawing with lines and a point located within the lines (the blue square).
 [before boundary command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CMjk.png)

This image depicts the same drawing with the desired output once the autocad boundary command has been run using that point.
[after boundary command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QZVe.png)

The autocad boundary command has located the closest lines surrounding the point and highlighted them. I've been trying to achieve the same outcome in C# without relying on the autocad editor commands. My only idea was some sort of flood fill algorithm but this seems very inefficient and verbose for what shouldn't really be a difficult problem to solve.

I'd very much appreciate any suggestions or pseudocode that could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Here's a reference to the autocad boundary command as I don't have the rep to post more than two links in a question https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-5072D0D0-5DB7-4649-8B2F-1FD5A3FA3643-htm.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Editor.TraceBoundary() method.

```
public unsafe DBObjectCollection TraceBoundary(Point3d seedPoint, bool detectIslands)
```

http://www.through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2010/06/tracing-a-boundary-defined-by-autocad-geometry-using-net.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately my biggest constraint is that I am unable to use any autocad editor api functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have not described how your segments are organized.

Build a ray from given point in horizontal direction, find the first intersected segment. Get upper end of that segment and determine what neighbor segment the first in clockwise order . Continue with the second end of that segment and so on until the first segment is met again.

Comment: The line segments are not organised or grouped at all. Thanks for your suggestion, I shall give it a go.

Comment: But their ends should coincide.

Comment: Yes, I have pre-processed the line segments to ensure that their ends coincide.

Comment: OK, so perhaps you already have pairing/adjacency between segments, and traversal along the closed path is quite easy task.

Answer (score 0):

What boundary command is doing is finding a 2d point inside a closed polygon. There are many algorithms that cover this [(see here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon).
However, because you are saying your lines aren't grouped you have to break this into two steps. 
First step is to detect if a line is part of a polygon shape and store all these polygons in your data. Next is to find the closest line that belongs to a polygon shape. Once you detect that you have found your solution.
For finding nearset line segment to a point, a simple search will get you alot of results.

Good luck